# NancyFx cannot find NewtonSoft reference in Razor View Engine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, json.net, nancy

I've got a simple partial:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <label>view model</label>
    <textarea class="form-control btn-xs" rows="12">@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)</textarea>
</div>
```

the following have not worked:

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json
```

in partial or primary cshtml, nor:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="Newtonsoft.Json" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

in Views/Web.config. I still get:

```
The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

or

```
The name 'JsonConvert' does not exist in the current context
```

Comment: Do you realy have the Newtonsoft package installed?

Comment: I googled and looks like there's a specific package for nancy. Should be your issue. Take a look here https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nancy.Serialization.JsonNet/0.22.2

Comment: I have package installed, and it works in my project outside of a View.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add the following to my Web.config to get rid of this error

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="razor" type="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.RazorConfigurationSection, Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor" />
  </configSections>

  <razor disableAutoIncludeModelNamespace="false">
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="Newtonsoft.Json" />
    </assemblies>
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="Newtonsoft.Json" />
    </namespaces>
  </razor>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score -1):

Stupid question: Have you added the Json.Net nuget package to your project?

The simplest explanation for the last attempt not working would simply be that.

Comment: Yes, I have the proper package installed. The references to Newtonsoft.Json work fine outside of the views.